# Scala - Unexpected Nullable Found - Left Join

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, left-join, nullable

I have been receiving an UnexpectedNullableFound error with my Scala application and I was hoping for some assistance on how to correct this.

The error:-

```
[error] application - Unable to log user in. An exception was thrown
java.lang.RuntimeException: Left(UnexpectedNullableFound(ColumnName(.language,Some(language))))                                                                                             at anorm.MayErr$$anonfun$get$1.apply(MayErr.scala:35) ~[anorm_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]                                                                                                 at anorm.MayErr$$anonfun$get$1.apply(MayErr.scala:34) ~[anorm_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]                                                                                                 at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:98) ~[scala-library-2.11.12.jar:na]                at anorm.MayErr.get(MayErr.scala:34) ~[anorm_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
        at anorm.Row$class.unsafeGet(Row.scala:103) ~[anorm_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
        at anorm.Cursor$ResultRow.unsafeGet(Cursor.scala:77) ~[anorm_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]        at anorm.Row$class.apply(Row.scala:80) ~[anorm_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]                      at anorm.Cursor$ResultRow.apply(Cursor.scala:77) ~[anorm_2.11-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
        at models.UserModel$$anonfun$findUserByEmailAndPassword$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(UserModel.scala:162) ~[classes/:na]
        at models.UserModel$$anonfun$findUserByEmailAndPassword$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(UserModel.scala:156) ~[classes/:na]
```

And this is the code where I think it might be causing this error:-

```
  def findUserByEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String, browserHeaders: String, ip: String): Option[SocialUser] = DB.withConnection(db) { implicit c =>
    SQL"""
    select * from find_user_by_email_and_password($email, $password, $browserHeaders, inet($ip))
    """().map(row => (row[Option[Long]]("id"),
      row[Option[String]]("email"),
      row[Option[Int]]("verification"),
      row[Option[Boolean]]("on_mailing_list"),
      row[Option[Boolean]]("tfa_enabled"),
      row[Option[String]]("pgp"),
      row[String]("language")) match {
        case (Some(id: Long),
          Some(email: String),
          Some(verification: Int),
          Some(on_mailing_list: Boolean),
          Some(tfa_enabled: Boolean),
          pgp: Option[String],
          language: String) =>
          Some(SocialUser(id, email, verification, language, on_mailing_list, tfa_enabled, pgp))
        case _ =>
          None
      }
    ).head
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to take something `row[String]("language")` from the column `language`, but this column contains `NULL` value.

You need to write it as `row[Option[String]]("language")` or make the language column `NOT NULL` in the database scheme.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your suggest also required me to add Some() in front of 'language: String)' line.